# how to do auto minimize in swing

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am testing some code using JWindow and that hide jframe, so I have to create minimize, maximize and close buttons for user friendly. How can I set state to frame when click on created buttons.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what you are asking.

Comment: pardon my english! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [`JFrame#setState`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setState%28int%29). You can do:

```
myFrame.setState(Frame.ICONIFIED)
```

As the implementation of a listener of the buttons.